# MYSQL & Phpmyadmin are not showing the same DB

Tags: mysql

I am running XAMMP & I installed MYSQL through Homebrew with `brew install mysql`

However when I run `show databases;`in the terminal after logging in with `mysql -u root`

I get this

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| new_cms_db         |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but in phpmyadmin when I command `show databases;`

[image]

I have browsed every forum and stack overflow question and I cannot find anything that resolves this.

### EDIT

[image]

Comment: Xampp has an mysql server installation => result with phpmyadmin. When installing mysql with brew you will have installed another mysql server with own databases => databases shown via the command line. That is why you probably got two different results.
=> Mysql port of xampp will probably be 3308, and mysql server (installed with brew) will have the default 3306 port, you will need to select which mysql server you want to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xampp will have installed a mysql server that is listening on port 3308 (this is used with phpadmin).

When installing mysql with brew it will install another mysql server on the mysql default port 3306. When using the command line `mysql -u root` without mentioning a port number it will automatically try to connect to mysql server listening in port 3306.

=> You have two different results of databases that are shown

Comment: I think you are right, but when I use
`mysql -u root -p --port=3308` it still shows the incorrect databases

Comment: This is correct, and for this reason I highly advise to not run two MySQL instances on the same machine (unless you have a really good reason for it). I recommend that you remove the Homebrew MySQL since XAMPP includes everything in one installer.